# Using class attribute instead of styleClass of a JSF component actually works, why?

Tags: class, jsf, jsf-2, attributes

As far as I understood, we needed to use `styleClass=` as the JSF components don't support using just `class=`.

I've noticed recently that some components that were using `class=` were still rendering correctly. As a minimal example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
       <h:inputText class="wut" anothertag="hi" value="me"/>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

This produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/individuallifefaz/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo"/>
        <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title></head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="j_idt5" value="me" class="wut"/>
    </body>

</html>
```

Why is this working? It's clearly not just passing through any unknown tags, as the `anothertag` is stripped out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually done by the view technology Facelets, not by the JSF component itself. Facelets has an [alias](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/4.0.0-RELEASE/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/faces/html/HtmlComponentHandler.java#L38) for `class` attribute which automatically maps to `styleClass`. This was implemented as part of support for `jsfc` attribute as used in "designer friendly Facelets" which should make things like this possible:

```
<input type="text" jsfc="h:inputText" class="foo" />
```

If you use JSF with a different view technology (although so far there's none which is a serious alternative to Facelets, and JSP is deprecated), then there's no guarantee that `<h:inputText class>` would work.

#### See also:

- [Is there a way to run a JSF page without building the whole project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504190/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-jsf-page-without-building-the-whole-project)