# How not to specify a <title> on all my JSF custom components

Tags: jsf, sonarqube

Following Oracle (and others) [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html), I have all my JSF components looking like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
>
<composite:interface>
    ...
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    ...
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Of course, it works properly, but SonarCube disagree with this (rule details [here](https://3layer.com.br/sonar/rules/show/Web:PageWithoutTitleCheck?layout=false)):

> "title" should be present in all pages

There are a couple of solutions :

- Asking Sonar to ignore these issues,
- Adding `<head>` and `<title>` tags,

But these looks like workarounds and I would like to set a permanent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DOCTYPE` and `html` tags are only mandatory when you author Facelets templates in a visual page designer. The Java EE tutorial's author had probably in mind that this kind of developers would become the largest group of JSF users. However, after all, this turned out to be untrue. In reality, these visual page designers generate terrible and non-semantic source code full of bad HTML/CSS practices, which one had to cleanup afterwards.

When you're authoring Facelets templates in a plain text editor (with syntax highlighting, of course), then you don't necessarily need these `DOCTYPE` and `html` tags in template compositions and composites. A root element of `<ui:composition>` and `<ui:component>` already suffices.

So, in your specific case, just use:

```
<ui:component 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
>
    <cc:interface>
        ...
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        ...
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

And then Sonar won't anymore incorrectly interpret it as a "plain" HTML page.

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)
- [Is there a way to run a JSF page without building the whole project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504190/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-jsf-page-without-building-the-whole-project)