# primefaces GMmap inside a dialog not rendering

Tags: google-maps, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to open a Gmap inside my jsf page, i tried these sample but it didn't work:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
<body>
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:commandButton type="button" icon="ui-icon-pin-s" value="Show Map"
            onclick="dlg.show()" />

        <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" width="625" height="400" modal="true">
            <p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID"
                style="width:600px;height:400px" widgetVar="mymap" />
        </p:dialog>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is: in composition, you have to include `<h:head></h:head>` to apply css, but any code from that have not been loaded. You need to add script to `/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml`

**template.xhtml**:

```
<h:head>
    // other here
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
```

**See also**:[understand the purpose of jsf ui:composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525050/understand-the-purpose-of-jsf-uicomposition)