# How can I update p:column in p:panelgrid?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having problems in update of my panelgrid columns
Below is my code in my xhtml file, datatable in treatmenthistory.xhtml is updated fine but searchresult.xhtml is not updated and you have to refresh the whole page to make it updated. So what can be the problem, two xhtml pages look like same, they both have datatables.

```
        <h:form>
            <p:panelGrid cellpadding="0" styleClass="results">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="1">
                        <ui:include src="/searchresult.xhtml" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column colspan="1">
                        <ui:include src="/treatmenthistory.xhtml" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

users:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="java.sun.com/jsf/core"  xmlns:h="java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:dataTable id="users" var="user1" styleClass="searchResult"
        widgetVar="userTable" value="#{KisiInfoProcess.kisiList}"
        emptyMessage="#{msg['noRecordsFound']}" dynamic="true"
        paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{user1.tcidno}"
        rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'highlight1' : 'highlight2'}"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex" selection="#{KisiInfoProcess.selectedOS}"
        selectionMode="single" paginatorPosition="bottom">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{KisiInfoProcess.onRowSelect}"
            process="@this" update=":form:users2" />
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['searchResultsPanel']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:column id="kisiid" sortBy="#{user1.kisiid}"
            filterBy="#{user1.kisiid}" styleClass="kisiid">

            <h:outputText value="#{user1.kisiid}" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.kisiid)" value="#{msg['protocolNo']}" />

        </p:column>
        <p:column id="ad" sortBy="#{user1.ad}" filterBy="#{user1.ad}"
            styleClass="ad">

            <h:outputText value="#{user1.ad}" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.ad)" value="#{msg['name']}" />

        </p:column>
        <p:column id="soyad" sortBy="#{user1.soyad}"
            filterBy="#{user1.soyad}" styleClass="soyad">

            <h:outputText value="#{user1.soyad}" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.soyad)" value="#{msg['surname']}" />

        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{user1.tcidno}" styleClass="tcidno"
            filterBy="#{user1.tcidno}" id="tcidno">

            <h:outputText value="#{user1.tcidno}" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.tcidno)" value="#{msg['identityNumber']}" />

        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{user1.ogrencino}" styleClass="ogrencino"
            filterBy="#{user1.ogrencino}" id="ogrencino">

            <h:outputText value="#{user1.ogrencino}" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.ogrencino)" value="#{msg['studentNumber']}" />

        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{user1.dogumtarihi}" styleClass="dogumtarihi"
            filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{user1.dogumtarihi}"
            id="dogumtarihi">

            <h:outputText value="#{user1.dogumtarihi}">
                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
            <p:watermark for="@(.dogumtarihi)" value="#{msg['dateOfBirth']}" />

        </p:column>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="modalDialogButton" style="min-width:8%"
                value="#{msg['newPatient']}"
                action="#{KisiInfoProcess.resetHastakayit}" update=":form:basic"
                oncomplete="PF('dlg2').show()" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

users2:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
    <p:dataTable id="users2" var="user" styleClass="patienthistory"
        emptyMessage="#{msg['noRecordsFound']}" widgetVar="muayeneTable"
        value="#{KisiInfoProcess.muayeneList}" dynamic="true"
        selection="#{KisiInfoProcess.selectedOS}" paginator="true" rows="10"
        rowKey="#{user.muayeneid2}"
        rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'highlight1' : 'highlight2'}"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex" selectionMode="single"
        paginatorPosition="bottom">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            listener="#{KisiInfoProcess.onRowSelectMuayene}" process="@this"
            update=":form:panel2,:form:protocolNo"
            oncomplete="PF('dlg3').show()" />
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['treatmentHistoryPanel']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:column sortBy="#{user.muayeneid2}" styleClass="muayeneid"
            filterBy="#{user.muayeneid2}" id="muayeneno2">

            <h:outputText value="#{user.muayeneid2}" style="width:5%" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.muayeneid)" value="#{msg['treatmentNo']}" />

        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{user.muayeneturuid2}" styleClass="muayeneturu"
            filterBy="#{user.muayeneturuid2}" id="muayeneturuid2">

            <h:outputText value="#{user.muayeneturuid2}" style="width:5%" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.muayeneturu)" value="#{msg['treatmentType']}" />

        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{user.tarih}" styleClass="tarih"
            filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{user.tarih}" id="tarih">

            <h:outputText value="#{user.tarih}" style="width:5%">
                <f:convertDateTime type="both" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm" />
            </h:outputText>
            <p:watermark for="@(.tarih)" value="#{msg['treatmentDate']}" />

        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{user.islemiyapan}" styleClass="islemiyapan"
            filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{user.islemiyapan}"
            id="userid2">

            <h:outputText value="#{user.islemiyapan}" style="width:5%" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.islemiyapan)" value="#{msg['treatmentDoctor']}" />

        </p:column>
        <p:column id="tanivarmi">

            <h:outputText style="width:5%" value="#{user.taniVarmi2}" />

        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="modalDialogButton2" style="min-width:8%"
                rendered="#{KisiInfoProcess.kisiSelected}"
                value="#{msg['newTreatment']}"
                action="#{KisiInfoProcess.resetMuayene}" update=":form:basic2"
                oncomplete="PF('dlg3').show()" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: try using ajax tag `<p:ajax event="yourEvent" process="@this" listener="#{yourListener}" ="targetID" />`

Comment: I tried your solution it updated once but then again didn't update that part, I didn't understand strange problem

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525050/understand-the-purpose-of-jsf-uicomposition. Tags outside an `ui:composition` are ignored. So the `h:form` does nothing

Comment: also without form tags still problem exists

Comment: without? You added them inside... That is good btw, but not in line with your comment

Comment: right without form tags nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

```
<p:panelGrid cellpadding="0" styleClass="results" id="someID">
```

And then when you do some action to change your dataTable's, set Update="someID" to refresh both pages. SomeID is your full id "someNameContainer:someID"

If you have one action to update both tables don't forget tu put process="idfirstTatbe idSecondTable" to process them both before update.

Comment: `<p:ajax id="ajax1" listener="#{InfoProcess.resetSearch}" event="click" process="users users2" update="resultpanel" oncomplete="PF('dlg2').hide()"/>`

Comment: I tried this but unluckily nothing happened can It be a bug in jsf or is it about jsf version ?

Comment: Where is your form, is resultpanel() your panelGrid that has bot pages included? Is is it surrounded by form or do both pages have their own form? Do you use prependId=false on your form's? Are you sure your real id's of component are users and users2. Can you verified that with developer tools or firebug?

Comment: resultpanel is panelgrid id, users and users2 are the id of datatables in included xhtml files, with or without h:form prependId=false only users2 is updated

Comment: You  didn't say about multiple forms? Do you have them, no ID on them? Send code of your pages, i could only guess that you you have multiple forms and not submitting one of them or you get an error in processing user page. Are datatable's only elements in pages? <p:chart no?

Comment: I edited my question by adding two included xhtml files

Comment: You can't have two forms with same id, you can't have prependId=false and then address elements with form:itemID.  Surround your whole panelgrid(resultpanel) with one <h:form>(without id and prependID) and delete forms from individual pages.  delete html tag in included pages and put ui:composition like this <ui:composition 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

Comment: update=":form:users2"  in first page change to update whole panelGrid

Comment: As I said before there is something wrong with with datatable with id of users, the other datatable with id users2 has no problem when I click to commandbutton it is updated

Comment: @DijanaCukic: if you use `prependId="false"` in your form, you still have to add the form id in the ajax update/render attributes, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/jsf-namingcontainer-and-uiform-with-prependid. Unfortunate, but true. Better to never use prependId="false" again...

Comment: @coderxyz24 yes because you are updating user2 so user2 is ok, however you are not updating user so user don't get updated. (at)Kukeltje if you will see the code he is using updates with form:id "update=":form:panel2, :form:protocolNo"

Comment: when I debug my code datatable is empty and when I use refresh button of my web browser then user datatable becomes empty

Comment: @dijanaCukic: yes I know OP is doing it right, I was referring to you post of 40 minutes ago. Interpreted your comment as that OP is using prependId and update in a wrong way

Comment: I'm getting "The class does not have property 'onRowSelect'" after I deleted html tags

Comment: <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            listener="#{KisiInfoProcess.onRowSelectMuayene}" process="@this"
            update="@form"
            oncomplete="PF('dlg3').show()" /> And second table <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{KisiInfoProcess.onRowSelect}"
            process="@this" update="@form" />   also change on commandButton if you want to update both tables on click if you wat to chat about it go to http://collabedit.com/574uw

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem, I removed

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.execute("PF('userTable').clearFilters()");
```

now I have another problem I have to clear filter of datatable

@DijanaCukic Thanks Dijana for spending your time to solve my problem

Comment: The best way to give thanks is by "**Checkmarking**" a users answer as the "Selected" answer, and/or **UpVoting** their answers and comments. Remember, you can Upvote all answers and comments that you find helpful. It's like free money, you can spend endlessly on upvotes. Upvotes motivate users to contribute their knowledge, and helps future users quickly find information useful for solving *their* problems. Thanks.