# Bootstrap not working under ui composition tag JSF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2.2

I am designing a website, in which i want to include my `Navbar` in all pages, the problem is that whenever I write `navbar` code inside `ui:composition` tag than `bootstrap` goes off. without this tag everything is working fine.

the Working code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<h:head>


    <title>JSF 2.x Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="enter,your,keywords,here" />
    <meta http-equiv="description"
        content="A short description of this page." />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="black.css"  />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css"  />

    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />

</h:head>
<h:body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Task</a>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Projects</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Objects</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Properties</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Property Types</button>

        </div>
        </nav>

</h:body>
</html>
```

But with the `ui:composition`, bootstrap is not working

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<h:head>
    <title>JSF 2.x Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="enter,your,keywords,here" />
    <meta http-equiv="description"
        content="A short description of this page." />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="black.css"  />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css"  />

    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />

</h:head>
<h:body>
<ui:composition>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Task</a>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Projects</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Objects</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Properties</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Property Types</button>

        </div>
        </nav>
</ui:composition>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't the code outside ui:compsition ignored ? Why don't you use templates and put bootstrap in there ? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525050/understand-the-purpose-of-jsf-uicomposition

Comment: everything is ignored inside or outside the composition tag

Comment: it wasnt' really a question - code outside of the <ui:composition> tags will be ignored. Hence my suggestion to use a template that includes both boostrap and your composition

Comment: Please use correct tags (read the tag description!) it is twitter-bootstrap and not 'bootstrapping'. And read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used and use 'library' correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ui:composition Tag is used to reference a template via its 'template' 
attribute like:

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
```

The template is just a regular faces file that contains one or more `<ui:insert>`
 tags with a name attribute that you can reference from the file using the  template using the `<ui:define>` tag.
For example if your template contains:

```
<ui:insert name="top">
```

than you can reference it from another file within the `<ui:composition>` tag like:

```
<ui:define name="top">
```

The resulting html will be the one created from the template only the `<ui:define>` parts are replaced by whatever html is generated in your `<ui:insert>` tag...
So, without the template you are not creating proper html, no head no body..